# Laravel Unique and Exists Validation - Class Does Not Exist

Tags: laravel, lumen

Okay I use lumen 5.4 and I am a little confused about something, I have always used these two validations like this:

```
$rules = [
    "field1" => "required|exists:users",
    "field2" => "required|unique:users"
];
$messages = [
    "field1.exists" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "field2.unique" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response($validator->errors(), 400);
}
```

just like the doc says, where "users" is the name of the table in the database.  However now all of a sudden I get

> Error 500 Class users does not exist

This confused me, checked the docs again and it says to use the table name, so I just assumed that there's been some update and it now uses the Model name instead so I tried that.

Thing is I have all my Models in a Models folder with the following namespace: `App\Models;`

So then I tried:

```
$rules = [
    ‘field1’ => "required|exists:User",
    ‘field2’ => "required|unique:User"
];
```

and

```
$rules = [
    ‘field1’ => "required|exists:\App\Models\User",
    ‘field2’ => "required|unique:\App\Models\User"
];
```

and

```
$rules = [
    ‘field1’ => "required|exists:App/Models/User",
    ‘field2’ => "required|unique:App/Models/User"
];
```

and

```
$rules = [
    ‘field1’ => "required|exists:App\\Models\\User",
    ‘field2’ => "required|unique:App\\Models\\User"
];
```

None of these worked, I have been coding in Java for a while now so it's possible that I may have forgotten my stuff and I am doing something wrong here.

**Edit:** Exception:

```
{
  "message": "Class users does not exist.",
  "code": -1,
  "status_code: 500,
  "debug": {
    "line": 334,
    "file": "/home/xxxxx/xxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/IlluminateRegistry.php",
    "class": "ReflectionException",
    "trace": [
    "#0 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/IlluminateRegistry.php(334): ReflectionClass->__construct('users')",
  "#1 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php(123): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\IlluminateRegistry->getManagerForClass('users')",
  "#2 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php(92): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\Validation\\DoctrinePresenceVerifier->getEntityManager('users')",
  "#3 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php(45): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\Validation\\DoctrinePresenceVerifier->select('users')",
  "#4 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php(612): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\Validation\\DoctrinePresenceVerifier->getCount('users', 'email', 'xxxxxx@rock...', NULL, NULL, Array)",
  "#5 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(338): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->validateUnique('email', 'xxxxxx@rock...', Array, Object(Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator))",
  "#6 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(253): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->validateAttribute('email', 'Unique')",
  "#7 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(278): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->passes()",
  "#8 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php(50): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->fails()",
  "#9 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController->register(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#10 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
  "#11 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()",
  "#12 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))",
  "#13 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(531): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)",
  "#14 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(741): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)",
  "#15 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(707): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerCallable(Array, Array)",
  "#16 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(681): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callLumenController(Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController), 'register', Array)",
  "#17 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(643): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerAction(Array)",
  "#18 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(623): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(Array)",
  "#19 [internal function]: Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#20 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#21 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/PrepareController.php(45): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#22 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\PrepareController->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
  "#23 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#24 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#25 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#26 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(778): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
  "#27 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(624): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
  "#28 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(598): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)",
  "#29 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(532): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)",
  "#30 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(781): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}()",
  "#31 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(534): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
  "#32 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Adapter/Lumen.php(103): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#33 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(513): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Adapter\\Lumen->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), 'v1')",
  "#34 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(126): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#35 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#36 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#37 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
  "#38 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(103): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
  "#39 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
  "#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
  "#41 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
  "#42 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
  "#43 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(778): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
  "#44 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(534): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
  "#45 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(475): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(NULL)",
  "#46 /home/disons5/public_html/xxxxxx/index.php(28): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->run()",
  "#47 {main}"
    ]
  }
}
```

After changing my validation rule to use my model instead of table name I now get this error:

```
{
  "message": "Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null",
  "status_code": 500,
  "debug": {
    "line": 93,
    "file": "/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "trace": [
      "#0 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php(45): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\Validation\\DoctrinePresenceVerifier->select('App\\\\Models\\\\User')",
      "#1 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php(612): LaravelDoctrine\\ORM\\Validation\\DoctrinePresenceVerifier->getCount('App\\\\Models\\\\User', 'email', 'xxxxxx@rock...', NULL, NULL, Array)",
      "#2 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(338): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->validateUnique('email', 'xxxxxx@rock...', Array, Object(Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator))",
      "#3 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(253): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->validateAttribute('email', 'Unique')",
      "#4 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/validation/Validator.php(278): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->passes()",
      "#5 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php(50): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->fails()",
      "#6 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController->register(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#7 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
      "#8 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()",
      "#9 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))",
      "#10 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(531): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)",
      "#11 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(741): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)",
      "#12 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(707): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerCallable(Array, Array)",
      "#13 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(681): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callLumenController(Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController), 'register', Array)",
      "#14 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(643): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callControllerAction(Array)",
      "#15 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(623): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(Array)",
      "#16 [internal function]: Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#17 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#18 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/PrepareController.php(45): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#19 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\PrepareController->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
      "#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#21 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#22 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#23 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(778): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
      "#24 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(624): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
      "#25 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(598): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)",
      "#26 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(532): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)",
      "#27 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(781): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}()",
      "#28 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(534): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
      "#29 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Adapter/Lumen.php(103): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#30 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Routing/Router.php(513): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Adapter\\Lumen->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), 'v1')",
      "#31 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(126): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#32 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#33 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#34 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
      "#35 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Request.php(103): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
      "#36 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
      "#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#38 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#39 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#40 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(778): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
      "#41 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(534): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))",
      "#42 /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(475): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(NULL)",
      "#43 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/index.php(28): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->run()",
      "#44 {main}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Honestly I'm not even familiar with laravel-doctrine I just follow the laravel/lumen docs always and that's what I've always used to build my apps.

Comment: a correct syntax is `unique:table_name,column_name`. So you are currently missing the column that should be unique.

Comment: I thought the column name was optional as long as the field under validation had the same name as the field in the database?

Comment: You are correct in that assumption as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique). I just found `field1` to be a strange column name :)

Comment: It checks the database table not the model. But I dont have idea why you get such error.

Comment: double check your class name and file name/location, and run `composer dumpautoload`. Your validation is correct, I think you didn't debug the error correctly (please share the full exception if it's not the case)

Comment: Done that already, several times.

Comment: Are you positive that the validation rules are the source of the error? If you remove both the `exists` and `unique` validation rules, do you still get the same error? If not check your error log for a full stack trace and post the details.

Comment: When I take out the exists and unique validation rules it works fines without any errors.

Comment: @fubar Added the full trace.

Comment: I cannot see anything obvious, and without having the entire codebase, I think it's going to be difficult for someone else to debug. I am still convinced that the error isn't with the validation rules and instead is with your User class definition instead. If you want to post more code, e.g. your routes/controllers for the request, model, etc, I'd be happy to look further. If not, no worries and good luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using `laravel-doctrine` package (from that stack trace). The [documentation](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/validation) said that to do `unique` validation, you should use 2 arguments:

```
/**
 * Store a new blog post.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:App\User,username',
    ]);
}
```

The `exists` validation:

```
/**
 * Store a new blog post.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|exists:App\User,username',
    ]);
}
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
$rules = [
    "field1" => "required|exists:App\User,field1",
    "field2" => "required|unique:App\User,field2"
];
$messages = [
    "field1.exists" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "field2.unique" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response($validator->errors(), 400);
}
```

### UPDATE

If you get error: `Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on null`, then you forget to decorate your [Doctrine Metadata](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/meta-data). In your case, you need to update `App\Models\User` class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $field1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $field2;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even consider that the validation rules might be different if using Laravel Doctrine. Go figure.

Comment: @fubar yeah, I just realized after I saw the stack trace. You may see [this](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm/blob/1.3/src/IlluminateRegistry.php#L326). Before LaravelDoctrine validating, `getManagerForClass` method is responsible to get the object manager associated with the validator.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on what my issue was however after changing it like you said I have a new error, have edited my post to include the new trace.

Comment: Alright I did a google search to learn more about laravel-doctrine after your answer and I learned a lot, I was actually using it in my project without realizing, the 2nd exception I posted was because I didn't do my models the "laravel-doctrine" way I suspect.  Anyway I disabled laravel-doctrine in my app and now validation works just fine so thanks!! :D

Comment: @user3718908 I updated my answer. You can still use Doctrine in Lumen, all you need is patience. And I just want you to know that using Doctrine is a lil bit challenging but looks promising in performance and scalability. But overall, it's all your call whether to use Eloquent or Doctrine.